# signalr group add

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

can i add e.g. username instead of *connection.id*. does it work? i'm asking this because over ConnectionId i can't send notification to the user, because ConnectionId always is changes?

Groups.Add("my_username", "mygroup1);

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, you must use a ConnectionID.  You can however do the following.

On your hub store a list of users mapped to connection IDs:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();
```

Then after a client connection has been started you can call into a method like:

```
myHub.server.createUser("MyUsername");
```

Of course on the server you'd have:

```
public void createUser(string userName) 
{
    // You'd create a User class that had both of the following properties
    var user = new User
    {
        UserName = userName,
        ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId
    };
    _users.TryAdd(user.ConnectionID, user);        
}
```

SO whenever you want to lookup a user via connection ID you still have context of his/her username via the _users dictionary.

Note: This code works via signalr 1.0 alpha +