# Adding username to groups in SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Is it possible to use the IUserIDProvider instead of ConnectionID when working with Groups? I have already found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850055/signalr-group-add), but that concerns the SignalR 1.0 version. I wonder, whether things have changed in 2.0.

So far, I was using the conventional

```
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "groupName");
```

However, it was difficult to keep track of the connected users when their connectionID was changed (the client is a Xamarin Android app and somehow, reconnection always resulted in creation of a new ConnectionID). Thus, when the client is connecting, I have added a header:

```
    public async Task<bool> Login(int waitMilis, string name)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(waitMilis);
            _connection.Headers.Add("userName", name);
            await _connection.Start();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            CallFailure(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And on server side, implemented the IUserIdProvider:

```
public class MyUserProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        else if (request.Headers != null && request.Headers["userName"] != null)
            return request.Headers["userName"].ToString();
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to do something like

```
Groups.Add("userName", "groupName");
```

but the Add method does not have an overload for IUserIdProvider. So, is there a possibility to combine the IUserIdProvider and working with Groups, or am I stuck to creating a ConcurrentDictionary and then calling this?

```
        foreach(User user in group.Users)
        {
            Clients.User(user.Name).SendMessage(message,
                group.LastUpdateIndex
                );
        }
```

It ruins the whole beauty and simplicity of the SignalR code :-/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't currently a method like `Groups.Add("userName", "groupName");` in SignalR.

I suggest adding users to their appropriate group(s) in `OnConnected`:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnected()
    {
        var userName = MyUserHelper.GetUserId(Context.Request);

        foreach (var groupName in GroupManager.GetJoinedGroups(userName))
        {
            await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you need to add an already connected user to a group, then you will likely need to send a message to the user using something like `Clients.User(userName).joinGroup(groupName)`. Each client with `userName` could then call the appropriate hub method to join `groupName`.

Comment: It's a year now, and I have encountered the same problem. Last year I was able to make a workaround using ConcurrentDictionary, with group name as key and users as list of values. However, this time ConcurrentDictionary is not an option, since the number of connected users can easily be in tens of thousands. I believe there was no change in the SignalR implementation since then, was there?